# How to resolve HTTP 405 error NotAllowedMethod

Tags: .net-core, microservices, azure-api-management, azure-aks

I created .Net Core Rest API service with two GET method. Locally in debug mode, everything works as expected. When I deploy this service on Azure Kubernetes service and behind API Management, on every call to these two GET method I receive HTTP 405 error. I tried with different endpoints, but any of cases didn't resolve this issue. Any idea?

Comment: The only dependency I believe is that the operation has to be GET in APIM. Do you know where the 405 is coming from?

Comment: Use Azure portal to make test call and see trace there.

Comment: Thank you guys for yours help. At the end I didn't found root causes for this errors, so I decided to recreate environments and now everything works as expected. In any case, thank you for yours help.